# with tensorflow and keras how to find the "category" of a given string

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

Hello ML/AI newbie here,

I'm asking this question because I've no idea about machine learning, ai, e.t.c and I've no idea how to continue, what questions to ask. Even if I accidentally find the solution i wouldn't know.

Ok, I followed this tutorial about "Text Classification" and it went pretty well, no problems up to here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g4O5UOH304&list=WL&index=8&t=0s

It classifies IMDB comments and checks if a review is "Positive" or "Negative", "0" or "1"

My question is

Let say I've my own dataset, similar to IMDB but instead of "0" and "1" I have several categories as numbers like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,...." for each string. So I need it to return one of these numbers (since it's learning let say two of them if it can't decide)

What should I do?
A link to a tutorial related to what I need would be great too.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

data = keras.datasets.imdb

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = data.load_data(num_words=3000)

word_index = data.get_word_index()

word_index = {k:(v+3) for k, v in word_index.items()}
word_index["<PAD>"] = 0;
word_index["<START>"] = 1;
word_index["<UNK>"] = 2;
word_index["<UNUSED>"] = 3;

reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])

train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post", maxlen=250)
test_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post", maxlen=250)

def decode_review(text):
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(i, "?") for i in text])

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 6))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

#model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics="accuracy")

x_val = train_data[:10000]
x_train = train_data[10000:]

y_val = train_labels[:10000]
y_train = train_labels[10000:]



fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)

print(results)


for index in range(20):
    test_review = test_data[index]
    predict = model.predict([test_review])
    if predict[0] > 0.8:
        print(decode_review(test_data[index]))
        print(str(predict[0]))
        print(str(test_labels[index]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your task is a multiclass classification problem and for this reason, you have to modify your output layer. you have two possibilities.

if you have 1D integer encoded target you can use sparse_categorical_crossentropy as loss function, softmax as the last activation and the dimension of the last dense output equal to the number of class to predict

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Otherwise, if you have one-hot encoded your target you can use categorical_crossentropy, softmax as the last activation and the dimension of the last dense output equal to the number of class to predict

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)).values

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

the usage of softmax enables to interpret the output as probability scores which sum to 1

when you compute the final prediction, to obtain the predicted class you can simply to in this way `np.argmax(model.predict(X), axis=1)`

these are some basic tutorials for multiclass text classification:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-lstm-using-tensorflow-2-0-d88627c10a35
- https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-lstm-1590bee1bd17

Comment: I'm guessing second one (one-hot encoded) will be better for my case. I like the idea of binary encoded categories. I'll test it. Thanks for you comment and everything. I'll upvote for now and if noone else post anything i'll accept your answer. Thanks.